# Update Statement SQL doesn't update every record

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Question**
I've been trying to solve this question for quite a while now. But I'm not getting any closer to fixing it. I select a group of people eligible for getting a contract renewal. Now I want to update everyone with a specific code, but some of the records are staying blank.

**What I've tried**
These are the queries I'm using. First for selecting the records:

```
INSERT INTO SELECTION (CLIENDTID, CREATED_DT, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CONTRACTEND_DATE, PRODUCT, MOBILE,TELEPHONE, STREET, HOUSENUMBER, ADDITIVE, POSTALCODE, CITY)

SELECT CLIENDTID, GETDATE(),FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, CONTRACTEND_DATE, PRODUCT, MOBILE,TELEPHONE, STREET, HOUSENUMBER, ADDITIVE, POSTALCODE, CITY
FROM CONTRACTS C (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN OPTINS O (NOLOCK) ON O.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
INNER JOIN HISTORY HIS(NOLOCK) ON HIS.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
WHERE 
(
    ((DATEDIFF(DD,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 26 AND 28) 
    AND 
    (O.MAIL=1 OR O.SMS=1 OR O.DM=1 OR 0.TELEPHONE=1 AND HIS.HISTORY IS NULL))
OR
    ((DATEDIFF(DD,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 19 AND 21) 
    AND  
    (HIS.HISTORY<10 OR HIS.HISTORY IS NULL)
    AND 
    O.SMS=1 AND C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL)
OR  
    ((DATEDIFF(DD,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 19 AND 21) 
    AND  
    (HIS.HISTORY<100 OR HIS.HISTORY IS NULL)
    AND 
    (O.SMS=0 OR C.MOBILE IS NULL) 
    AND 
    O.CALL=1  
    AND 
    (C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL OR C.TELEPHONE IS NOT NULL))
OR
    ((DATEDIFF(DD,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 12 AND 14) 
    AND  
    (HIS.HISTORY<100 OR HIS.HISTORY IS NULL) 
    AND 
    O.TELEPHONE=1 
    AND 
    (C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL OR C.TELEPHONE IS NOT NULL))
)
```

And then i use this query to update the records.

```
UPDATE S
SET CODE = CASE 
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 26 AND 28)  AND HIS.HISTORY IS NULL AND O.MAIL = 1 AND C.MAIL IS NOT NULL THEN 'MAIL'
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 26 AND 28)  AND HIS.HISTORY IS NULL AND O.DM = 1 AND (O.MAIL=0 OR C.MAIL IS NULL) THEN 'DM'
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 26 AND 28)  AND HIS.HISTORY IS NULL AND O.DM = 0 AND (O.MAIL=0 OR C.MAIL IS NULL) AND O.SMS=1 AND C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL THEN 'SMS'    
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 26 AND 28)   AND HIS.HISTORY IS NULL AND O.DM = 0 AND (O.MAIL=0 OR C.MAIL IS NULL) AND (O.SMS=0 OR C.MOBILE IS NULL) AND 
                              O.TELEPHONE=1 AND (C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL OR C.TELEPHONE IS NOT NULL) THEN 'EXPORT'                   
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 19 AND 21) AND (HIS.HISTORY<10 OR HIS.HISTORY IS NULL)
                              AND O.SMS=1 AND C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL THEN 'SMS'   
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 19 AND 21) AND (HIS.HISTORY<100 OR HIS.HISTORY IS NULL)
                              AND (O.SMS=0 OR C.MOBILE IS NULL) AND O.TELEPHONE=1 AND (C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL OR C.TELEPHONE IS NOT NULL) THEN 'EXPORT'
                              
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(DD, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, C.CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 12 AND 14) AND (HIS.HISTORY<100 OR HIS.HISTORY IS NULL)
                              AND O.TELEPHONE=1 AND (C.MOBILE IS NOT NULL OR C.TELEPHONE IS NOT NULL) THEN 'EXPORT'
                ELSE NULL
            END
    FROM SELECTION S(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN CONTRACTS C (NOLOCK) ON C.CLIENTID = S.CLIENTID
    INNER JOIN OPTINS O (NOLOCK) ON O.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    INNER JOIN HISTORY HIS(NOLOCK) ON HIS.CLIENTID = C.CLIENTID
    WHERE S.CREATED_DT>DATEADD(hh,-4,GETDATE())
```

So basically it's the same selection i'm using to extract the records. But while updating them quite a few stay blank. And when i check the blank records they should've been given a code.

Maybe a case when statement is not the way to go about it, but i don't know how else to pull this off.

Comment: Is there any reason you have splattered your code with *nolock*? This can *cause* exactly your issue.

Comment: Instead of `NULL` in the `SET CODE = ...`, try `N/A`, and check if the problem is with the joins (which I doubt) or in the `CASE WHEN...`

Comment: JUST STOP splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Here it is obvious you don't know what it does since you apply it to the updated table.

Comment: And how much effort did you save by typing ` DATEDIFF(DD...` vs ` DATEDIFF(day...`? And which is more easily read? In addition, your left join to HISTORY (update query) is implicitly converted into an inner join due to the WHERE clause - so they are not logically equivalent.

Comment: @SMor  The person who taught me SQL told me to always use Nolock because otherwise i'm locking the tables and other processes can't use them. But i guess that's not the whole story. If you could please explain to me why it so wrong to use it. You are correct, using an inner join would've been better. I will change that.

Comment: `NOLOCK` does prevent locking of tables, but the reason that you don't generally want to do that is that if the records are being updated then the `NOLOCK` means you can read the table "mid-transaction" or while it's being written to, and as a result the data may be in an inconsistent state. Without the `NOLOCK` the process would attempt to get a lock on the table so that nothing can be updating it while it's trying to read it. That will slow the system down (and for long running queries can create real issues for other processes), but hopefully also mean you get results you can trust.

Comment: Probably said-person didn't fully understand the default concurrency model and implications either; it's not an issue, just remove it where you see it in code where you can, it's part of the learning process.

Comment: Nolock does *not* prevent locking of anything. It allows you to perform dirty reads, repeatable reads and phantom reads, it can duplicate data or skip rows, it will still prevent an exclusive lock and can actually *cause* blocking.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample data, including of the rows which are mean to be updated but aren't and details of why you think they should have been.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the use `NOLOCK` isn't introducing data oddities by allowing "dirty reads", I see several possibilities for why not all the data in your `SELECTION` table is being updated.

1. The `INSERT` has the clause `S.CREATED_DT>DATEADD(hh,-4,GETDATE())`. If the `INSERT` was run more than 4 hours before the `UPDATE` then rows created by that `INSERT` won't be updated.
2. Your `UPDATE` for `EXPORT` (with `BETWEEN 19 AND 21` days) has a condition of `O.TELEPHONE = 1` while the `INSERT` uses `O.CALL = 1`. I'm guessing the latter is correct and you need to amend the `UPDATE` code accordingly.
3. The first part of the `WHERE` clause (for `BETWEEN 26 AND 28`) in your `INSERT` has some odd looking logic related to the `HISTORY` field update. I think the relevant code should be as I've given below. The order of operations (`AND` takes precedence over `OR`) means that my code is not equivalent to your code).
4. There may be other ways in which the the `BETWEEN 26 AND 28` set of records is introducing issues as the code there is not at all equivalent, and seems to rely on business logic rather than logical equivalence.

**Revised `26-28` Code for the `INSERT`**

```
((DATEDIFF(DD,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CONTRACTEND_DATE) BETWEEN 26 AND 28) 
AND 
HIS.HISTORY IS NULL
AND 
(O.MAIL=1 OR O.SMS=1 OR O.DM=1 OR O.TELEPHONE=1)
```

Note: I have assumed that `0.TELEPHONE` is a typo and should be `O.TELEPHONE`.

**A Different Approach**

If you are confident that one of the two pieces of code is correct, I'd suggest you use exactly the same code in all the relevant spots. Here's a simplified version of how to do that:

```
INSERT INTO SELECTION
SELECT *
FROM SOURCETABLE t
WHERE
(
CASE
    WHEN t.A=1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN t.B=1 THEN 'B'
    ELSE NULL
END
) IS NOT NULL

UPDATE s
SET s.Target = 
    CASE
        WHEN t.A=1 THEN 'A'
        WHEN t.B=1 THEN 'B'
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
SELECTION s
JOIN SOURCETABLE t ON s.ID = t.ID
WHERE
    (
    CASE
        WHEN t.A=1 THEN 'A'
        WHEN t.B=1 THEN 'B'
        ELSE NULL
    END
    ) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Jacqueline, if the above has solved your issues please mark the answer as "accepted". If it didn't solve them, but helped you solve them, you might still want to accept the answer or perhaps to post and accept your own answer. Alternatively, if none of this has helped, please let us know what issues you're still having, and perhaps update your question accordingly (and with changes suggested by the previous comments). 


If not, please leave a comment saying what issues you're still experiencing. It may be that while note actually solving.